# How to install prozess on a ubuntu machine using npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

On the command `npm install prozess` it giving following error:

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/local/kafka/NodeKafka# sudo npm install prozess
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/prozess
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/prozess
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/prozess/-/prozess-0.4.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/prozess/-/prozess-0.4.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/1.3.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffermaker/0.0.10
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.2.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/binary/0.3.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/crc32/0.2.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bignum/0.6.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/1.3.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/binary/0.3.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/-/underscore-1.3.3.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/binary/-/binary-0.3.0.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffermaker/0.0.10
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffermaker/-/buffermaker-0.0.10.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.2.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/-/buffer-crc32-0.2.1.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/crc32/0.2.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/crc32/-/crc32-0.2.2.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bignum/0.6.0
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/binary/-/binary-0.3.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/-/underscore-1.3.3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/-/buffer-crc32-0.2.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/crc32/-/crc32-0.2.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffermaker/-/buffermaker-0.0.10.tgz

> bignum@0.6.0 install /usr/local/kafka/NodeKafka/node_modules/prozess/node_modules/bignum
> node-gyp configure build

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffers
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chainsaw
make: Entering directory `/usr/local/kafka/NodeKafka/node_modules/prozess/node_modules/bignum/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bignum/bignum.o
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bignum/bignum.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory `/usr/local/kafka/NodeKafka/node_modules/prozess/node_modules/bignum/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-49-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/kafka/NodeKafka/node_modules/prozess/node_modules/bignum
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.13
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
unbuild bignum@0.6.0
unbuild prozess@0.4.0
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/chainsaw
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffers
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/traverse
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/traverse
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Does anyone know what is the dependency of this (bignum) and the way to install `prozess`?

Comment: `g++: Command not found`. Have you installed `build-essential`?

Comment: yes, exactly missed it...